# iPhone X simulator

Tags: iphone

I have to do some UI testings on iPhone X, but I don't have a device or even a Mac. Is there any way to test an iPhone app on an iPhone X simulator on a Windows environment.

Answer (score 1):

[Browserstack](https://www.browserstack.com) have recently added iPhone X to their real device list.

It'll cost you, and the price will vary depending on where you are and what you want out of it, but you can spin up an iPhone X (among loads of other phones) within 60 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

As someone already mentioned there are a number of devices or testing services available and most have either a free tier of usage or some amount of time where the service is free. These work in the short term but can be a bit slow:

- [BrowserStack](https://www.browserstack.com/)
- [SauceLabs](https://saucelabs.com/)
- [Amazon Device Farm](https://aws.amazon.com/device-farm/)

Realistically if you are doing any any serious or long term testing you'll want to get your hands on a real device. This might mean purchasing directly, renting one (google search) or finding a device lab in your area where you can rent time / space.

Comment: Looking at their device list, I don't think Amazon Device Farm supports remote access to an iPhone X (http://awsdevicefarm.info/) - I might be misreading it though

Comment: Also, what makes you say that BrowserStack or SauceLabs will only work in the short term? Browserstack connect you to a real iPhone X, which is as good as having a physical device in front of you... which means there's no benefit in purchasing one

Comment: @trashpanda Don't get me wrong, I like SauceLabs but their pricing for a single physical device is like $90/month for one year or $120 if you pay month to month. That's for roughly 8 hours worth of usage per month. So they are good if you need one device at a time and for only a few hours. Otherwise they seem more like a short term solution compared to buying your own and having full access to it.